How can I explode a list to column and use another list as an column name?
I have table which has data like below,



names
values




[a,b,c]
[1,2,3]


[a,b,c]
[4,5,6]



How can I transform this into below table using spark sql (SELECT) without hardcoding index and without hardcoding column names?



a
b
c




1
2
3


4
5
6




You can't achieve the results you expect just by using spark sql alone.
Check below code.
schema = df.selectExpr('''
    explode_outer(names) as names
''')
.distinct()
.orderBy("names")
.selectExpr('''
    concat_ws(
            ',', 
            transform(
                collect_list(names), 
                t -> concat(t, ' INT')
            )
    ) as names
''')
.collect()[0][0]

schema
'a INT,b INT,c INT'

df
.selectExpr(f'''
    from_json(
        to_json(
            map_from_arrays(names, values)
        ), 
        '{schema}'
    ) as output
''')
.selectExpr("output.*")
.show(10, False)
+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c  |
+---+---+---+
|1  |2  |3  |
|4  |5  |6  |
+---+---+---+


I think the below code can be converted int sql but determining
names_list will still have to be perfomed outside.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Create DataFrame Example").getOrCreate()

data = [
    (['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]),
    (['c', 'b', 'a'], [4, 5, 6])
]

schema = ['names', 'values']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show(n=20, truncate=False)
df_with_map = df.withColumn("name_value_map", expr("map_from_arrays(names, values)"))
# this assumes the names list will remain constant throughout all rows. Order may vary which is ok.
names_list = df.limit(1).select(col("names")).rdd.map(lambda x: x["names"]).collect()[0]
print(f"{names_list=}")

# this doesn't assume those constraints.
expr_list = [col("name_value_map").getItem(ele).alias(ele) for ele in names_list]
df_final1 = df_with_map.select(*expr_list)
df_final1.show(n=20, truncate=False)

distinct_names_df = df.select(explode("names").alias("name")).distinct()
distinct_names = [row['name'] for row in distinct_names_df.collect()]
print(f"{names_list=}")

expr_list = [col("name_value_map").getItem(ele).alias(ele) for ele in distinct_names]
df_final2 = df_with_map.select(*expr_list)
df_final2.show(n=20, truncate=False)

Output :
+---------+---------+
|names    |values   |
+---------+---------+
|[a, b, c]|[1, 2, 3]|
|[c, b, a]|[4, 5, 6]|
+---------+---------+

names_list=['a', 'b', 'c']
+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c  |
+---+---+---+
|1  |2  |3  |
|6  |5  |4  |
+---+---+---+

names_list=['a', 'b', 'c']
+---+---+---+
|c  |b  |a  |
+---+---+---+
|3  |2  |1  |
|4  |5  |6  |
+---+---+---+


What if names column contains different values other than [ a, b, c ] ? How this logic works ?

yeah, the names_list is extracted from the first row of data. I have added two methods to determine the names list. The first method assumes the names will remain constant from row to row, the order of the names can vary from one row to another. The second method determines all the unique names can occur throughout the data. so if first row contains [a,b,c] , second row might contain [d,a,e].

if you're open to exploding and pivoting, we can explode the name-value pairs to create individual columns which can be pivoted.
here's an example
# create name-value pairs as struct and an arbitrary row ID
out1_sdf = data_sdf. \
    withColumn('id', func.row_number().over(wd.partitionBy().orderBy('values'))). \
    withColumn('name_val', func.zip_with('names', 'values', lambda a, b: func.struct(func.lit(a).alias('name'), func.lit(b).alias('val')))). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---------+---------+---+------------------------+
# |names    |values   |id |name_val                |
# +---------+---------+---+------------------------+
# |[a, b, c]|[1, 2, 3]|1  |[{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}]|
# |[a, b, c]|[4, 5, 6]|2  |[{a, 4}, {b, 5}, {c, 6}]|
# +---------+---------+---+------------------------+

# explode the array of structs to create columns
out2_sdf = out1_sdf. \
    selectExpr('id', 'inline(name_val)'). \
    show()

# +---+----+---+
# | id|name|val|
# +---+----+---+
# |  1|   a|  1|
# |  1|   b|  2|
# |  1|   c|  3|
# |  2|   a|  4|
# |  2|   b|  5|
# |  2|   c|  6|
# +---+----+---+

# pivot the name column
out2_sdf. \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('name'). \
    agg(func.first('val')). \
    drop('id'). \
    show()

# +---+---+---+
# |  a|  b|  c|
# +---+---+---+
# |  1|  2|  3|
# |  4|  5|  6|
# +---+---+---+


you could easily convert the steps to SQl till out2_sdf, but the pivot operation is much easier in dataframe API.
data_sdf.createOrReplaceTempView('data_tbl')
spark.sql('''
    select id, inline(name_val)
    from (
        select *, row_number() over (order by values) as id, zip_with(names, values, (a, b) -> struct(a as name, b as val)) as name_val
        from data_tbl)
''').show()

# +---+----+---+
# |id |name|val|
# +---+----+---+
# |1  |a   |1  |
# |1  |b   |2  |
# |1  |c   |3  |
# |2  |a   |4  |
# |2  |b   |5  |
# |2  |c   |6  |
# +---+----+---+


The desired effect cannot be achieved if the values in the names column are not the same. If the values in the names column are the same, it can be achieved as follows:

The content of the MySQL table is as follows:


Process the table data through Spark
import com.alibaba.fastjson2.JSON;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MySQLDemo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
        .setMaster("local")
        .setAppName("read MySQL");
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .config(sparkConf)
        .getOrCreate();

  // MySQL Connection information
  String database = "test";
  String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/" + database;
  String dbTable = "test";
  String user = "root";
  String password = "root";

  // Read MySQL table information
  Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
          .format("jdbc")
          .option("url", jdbcUrl)
          .option("dbtable", dbTable)
          .option("user", user)
          .option("password", password)
          .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
          .load();

  // show Dataset
  df.show();

  // Build schema information based on the names column
  Row names = df.select(df.col("names")).first();
  String cols = names.getString(0);
  List<String> colList = JSON.parseArray(cols, String.class);
  List<StructField> structFields = new ArrayList<>();
  colList.forEach(col -> {
    structFields.add(new StructField(col, DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty()));
});
  StructField[] fields = new StructField[]{};
  StructType schema = new StructType(structFields.toArray(fields));

  // Build a dataset based on the values column
  Dataset<Row> values = df.select(df.col("values"));
  values.show();
  List<Row> resList = new ArrayList<>();
  for(Row row : values.collectAsList()) {
      String vals = row.getString(0);
      List<Integer> valueList = JSON.parseArray(vals, Integer.class);
      Object[] datas = new Object[]{};
      Row res = RowFactory.create(valueList.toArray(datas));
      resList.add(res);
  }
  Dataset<Row> resDataSet = spark.createDataFrame(resList, schema);
  resDataSet.show();

  // close SparkSession
  spark.close();

 }

}


The execution result is as follows:



